# Unable to install PIP & PYMSSQL in docker

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu

I am trying to build a docker image with

1. Python
2. PIP
3. pymssql

below is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y telnet && apt-get install -y ksh && apt-get install -y python2.7.x && apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential && apt-get -y clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN pip install pymssql==2.1.3
ENTRYPOINT ['python']
```

it is throwing the following error:

[image]

Comment: Please follow the best practices for writing a Dockerfile: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/. Also, the packages can be listed one by one after the first `apt-get install -y`, no need to repeat the command. Furthermore, the number of layers in your Dockerfile will be bigger because you are using `RUN` three times instead of once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind to use python3 (otherwise use virtual env) I rate you to do :

```
RUN apt-get install python3-pip
```

Then you will be able to install whatever pip package you need : by doing :

```
RUN pip3 install <your_pip_pkg>
```

Comment: @mugil-karthikeyan did it work ?

Answer (score 1):

Python-pip is only available on Ubuntu Bionic. see [python-pip](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python-pip).

You need to switch from focal to bionic. Universe repository should be enabled.